# Panels in foundation 6 not rendering

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, panel, zurb-foundation-6

new to foundation 6 here so probably missing something simple. Im trying to have panels render but its simply just not showing for me. Is there something ive missed?

Whether or not i put the div = panels, in or not, makes no difference. It looks the same as before or after.

Stupid question but would i have to run this from a web service for these to render?

I installed foundation 6 using command line prompts.

Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Site Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="panel">
          <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="top-bar-left">
          <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
            <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
            <li class="has-submenu">
              <a href="#">One</a>
              <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
                <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
          <div class="top-bar-right">
            <ul class="menu">
              <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
              <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-2 columns">
        <div class="large-2 columns">

        <a class="button" href="#"> button 1</a>
        <a class="button" href="#"> button 2</a>
        <a class="button" href="#"> button 3</a>
        <a class="button" href="#"> button 4</a>
        </div>

        <!--  <ul class="large-block-grid-1">

        <li><a class="button" href="#"> button 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" href="#"> button 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" href="#"> button 3</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" href="#"> button 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        -->

      </div>

      <div class="large-10 columns">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
          <div class="panel">
            <p>Content A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
          <div class="panel">
            <p>Content B</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
          <div class="panel">
            <p>Content C</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="background-color:#cccccc;">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <p bg-color="red">Footer</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/what-input/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @callium, if Colin's answer works, can you check it off as an answer please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Foundation 6 Callout Docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/callout.html):

> Callouts combine panels and alerts from Foundation 5 into one generic container component.

Use the class `.callout` instead of `.panel` in Foundation 6.